# Python losing performance writing to disk over time

Tags: python, file, data-mining, shelve

I have written a code to take an input from a file of very big data, perform some simple processing on it and then store it in a shelve dictionary format. I have 41 million entries to process. However, after I write 35 million entries to the shelve dict, performance suddenly drops and eventually completely halts. Any idea what I can do to avoid this?

My data is on twitter and it maps user screen names to their ID's. Like so:

```
Jack 12
Mary 13
Bob 15
```

I need to access each of these by name very quickly. Like: when I give `my_dict[Jack]` it returns `12`.

Comment: @eumiro yes that is exactly what I am doing..

Comment: Swapping is **much** slower than working in RAM. Change your data structure, write into DB (sqlite should suffice)… without more information about your data it is difficult to help.

Comment: updated my question with more details on the data. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using something more low-level. Shelve performance can be quite low, unfortunately. This doesn't explain the slow-down you are seeing though.

For many disk-based indexes it *helps* if you can initialize them with an expected size, so they do not need to reorganize themselves on the fly. I've seen this with a *huge* performance impact for on-disk hash-tables in various libraries.

As for your actual goal, have a look at:

http://docs.python.org/library/persistence.html

in particular the `gdbm, dbhash, bsddb, dumbdbm` and `sqlite3` modules.

`sqlite3` is probably not the fastest, but the easiest to use one. After all, it has a command line SQL client. `bsddb` probably is faster, in particular if you tune `nelem` and similar parameters for you data size. And it does have a lot of language bindings, too; likely even more than sqlite.

Try to *create* your database with an initial size of 41 million, so it can optimize for this size!